# Multiple row query

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a query that can return multiple rows and I want to execute another query for each row that first query return. I tried with cursor but it just execute first row and then ends. What is right way to do it?

```
/*Order nubmer*/
DECLARE @orderVar AS INT
SET @orderVar = 1002308304
/*Print order*/
PRINT 'Broj shipmenta je '+CAST(@orderVar as varchar)
/*SELECT shipmentID*/
DECLARE @shipmentIDVar AS INT
SELECT @shipmentIDVar = ID FROM APSisak.ImportExport.Shipment where OrderNo= @orderVar
PRINT 'Broj shipmentID je '+CAST(@shipmentIDVar as varchar)
/*SELECT laneShipmentID*/
DECLARE @laneShipmentIDVar as INT
DECLARE laneCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT LaneID
FROM APSisak.Queue.LaneShipment
WHERE APSisak.Queue.LaneShipment.LaneID = @shipmentIDVar    
OPEN laneCursor
SELECT @laneShipmentIDVar = ID FROM APSisak.Queue.LaneShipment
PRINT CAST(@laneShipmentIDVar as varchar)/*testni print*/
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)    
BEGIN/*LOOP for laneShipmentID*/
/*Print laneShipmentID*/
PRINT 'LaneShipmentID je '+CAST(@laneShipmentIDVar as varchar)
FETCH NEXT FROM laneCursor 
INTO @laneShipmentIDVar/*Next laneShipmentID*/
/*Select vehicleID*/    
DECLARE @vehicleIDVar as INT
END/*END lane*/    
CLOSE laneCursor
DEALLOCATE laneCursor
```

This returns just
LaneShipmentID je 16725
and it should be
LaneShipmentID je 16725
LaneShipmentID je 16726

Thanks

Comment: Well, really not sure why you think you even need a cursor here, but the problem is you need to `FETCH NEXT` after `OPEN`, and then `FETCH NEXT` inside the loop. You're only doing the one inside the loop. Also be careful about using `varchar` without indicating the max length, in some cases that will lead to truncation with no warning or error.

Comment: Yuch,,this code would benefit from some line spacing and indentation. Also I  prefer to see declared variables where possible at the start using default values rather than set where appropriate

Comment: Basically because I do not now any other way to do some query for each row from previous query. There will never be more than 4 rows in first query. Thanks for varchar advice I corrected it.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple join? Alternatively you could use a lateral join to combine both queries. It would be much more efficient.

Comment: First query gives me 2 rows from one table and with this 2 rows I need to find 2 rows in next table and add these values to variable. So I do not think that union is the way.